# How to position an <img> anywhere inside a CSS <div> and have text flow around it

Tags: css

I have a `div` full of text. I want to put an image into it at any preferred location and have the text flow around it. In fact I'd like to be able to do the same thing several times, to have ads or photos appear within the text of the article.

If you try this by placing the image with a `position:relative` then it obscures the text beneath it. Any solution?

LATE ADDITION: `float` is not what I'm looking for because I want to be able to position the ads/images anywhere within the text div, not only in its top corners. Thanks.

Comment: float it, that's what float is intended for.

Comment: Float will only work for the top left or top right. Other than that what you want is not currently possible with CSS although there is CSS Shapes / Exclusions but support is very limited.